# Hefeweizen final gravity too high

Tags: final-gravity, wheat-beer

I started my Hefeweizen with a OG of 1.054 and used Wyeast 3068.  The wort was well aerated but after 3 weeks my gravity is still 1.020 which seems a little high. The gravity reading I took a week ago was also 1.020.  Could this be because liquid yeast has a much lower cell count then dry yeast?  Should I pitch more yeast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your brew notes, as many details as possible are appreciated and limits the speculations in answers.

Solutions differ for many causes of the stuck fermentaion.

If I had to guess, it may have got too cold, raise temp to 75°F. Or the mash was above 158° and the yeast ignored the more complex sugars.

Comment: This was an extract brew, no mash or steeping grains.  The temperature during fermentation was 70 degrees.

Comment: @js911 check the date on the yeast. Generally at the use by date almost 1/2 the cells are dead, if it was stored properly. May have stuck from underpitch.

Comment: @ Evil Zymurgist The yeast has a manufactured date of Aug 28 and I believe liquid yeast is recommended for six months so this was close to the use by date but not over.  Do you think I should pitch more yeast?

Comment: @js911 a repitch is really the only recourse you have, unless you blend with another batch. Make sure to get the full effect of the smack pack, let the mini starter swell the pack well and repitch. Wyeast says 6mo should still have good viability IF stored and handled properly.